# CMake: Checking the return status of an external command or if a file is empty

Tags: cmake, grep, doxygen

I want to run Doxygen from CMake, then search the output for warnings and errors, and fail the target if any are found:

```
doxygen tools/doxygen/Doxyfile 2> outputs/doxygen_results.txt
test ! `grep "warning\|error" doxygen_results.txt`
```

How do I do this second part in the accursèd CMake? Bonus marks if you can show me how to make it work in Windows too.

Here is my current CMake snippet:

```
add_custom_target(docs
        COMMAND echo "Generating documentation"
        COMMAND doxygen tools/doxygen/Doxyfile 2> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doxygen_results.txt
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```

Comment: Which version iof doxygen are you using? Why using a grep on a redirected file? Why not using the possibility to redirect the warnings etc to a file (see setting `WARN_LOGFILE` or even better use the return value of the doxygen process (see here also `WARN_AS_ERROR` and especially here the `WARN_AS_ERROR=FAIL_ON_WARNINGS`.

Comment: As a side note: Why using `COMMAND echo "Generating documentation"` and not `COMMENT "Generating documentation"`?  From the cmake documentation: `COMMENT

    Display the given message before the commands are executed at build time`

Comment: COMMENT, I'm sure I've used before, so yes, that's great.

The others I'm not using because how would I know to use them? CMake's documentation is utterly bewildering and incomprehensible and frankly, the worst documentation for a widely used system I have ever come across.

EDIT: I see these are Doxygen things, not CMake things, :-)

Comment: I'm on Doxygen 1.8.17

Comment: The `FAIL_ON_WARNINGS` is introduced in doxygen 1.9.0, so for the 1.8.17 version you have to use `WARN_AS_ERROR=YES` with the big disadvantage of only 1 message. The version of 1.8.17 is from December 2019, the current version is 1.9.2 so I would advise to update.